# Can swarming locusts act as a vector for any human pathogens?

Tags: entomology, epidemiology, coronavirus, infectious-diseases

What human pathogens can the locusts currently swarming in Africa act as a vector for?

E.g. can the locust swarm ['become a reservoir for'](https://old.reddit.com/r/Coronavirus/comments/g3n6gq/second_african_locust_swarm_of_the_year_20_times/fns7wsr/) SARS-CoV-2? Measles? Ebola?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're getting close votes -- this post is not asking for an opinion. Close-voters, please review the guidelines for voting to close. Thanks.

Comment: we ask that all posters do their own research before posting here and indicate what research you've done. I invite you to explore coronaviruses in general to better understand their regular infection patterns.. Report back what you've found (by editing your post) and let us know what is still unsure to you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have not heard of locusts being a vector for any pathogen. For immunocompromised people, they can on rare occasions be infected by bacteria carried in the guts of insects. For desert locusts, their main gut bacteria is Pantoea agglomerans (Enterococcus agglomerans). This species has been listed as a pathogen of immunocompromised patients.

Comment: Should I delete?